# ADB não reconhece Android 4.2.2 no ubuntu

Tags: android, ubuntu

Estou a trabalhar em *ubuntu 13.04*, e acabei de receber um *tablet* com *Android 4.2.2* diretamente dum fabricante e não estou a conseguir que o ADB reconheça o *tablet*, e consequentemente não consigo fazer *debug*.

Já tentei:

- reiniciar o *Android* e o PC;
- reiniciar o ADB (alias quase todos os comandos do ADB);
- o *Android* tem a depuração USB ligada;

Já testei, com diferentes SDK, em *ubuntu*, em Windows XP, Windows 7 e Windows 8 e nada.
Em *windows* se for ao gestor de dispositivos ele aparece com o ponto de exclamação.

Vi [aqui](http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html) que precisava de definir as regras `undev` e segui estes passos:

```
# lsusb
```

> Bus 001 Device 011: ID 1f3a:100b

```
# sudo gedit /etc/udev/rules.d/99-android.rules
```

> SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="1f3a", ATTR{idProduct}=="100b",
>   MODE="0666", OWNER="meu-login"

```
# sudo service udev restart
```

Mas continua sem reconhecer o dispositivo.

Fonte [ubuntu-precise-install-android-sdk](http://bernaerts.dyndns.org/linux/74-ubuntu/245-ubuntu-precise-install-android-sdk)

Alguém imagina o que poderá ser?

Comment: Tentou criar o arquivo com o prefixo `51` em vez de `99`? Caso negativo, tente criar mesmo que fique duplicado.

Comment: Sim já tentei com os dois, 51 e 99.

Comment: Tipo, a tabela do Google não fornece o `idVendor` pra RFTECH. Tente entrar em contato com o suporte deles pra ver se eles disponibilizam esse `id` pra você. Me parece que o problema pode ser esse.

Comment: Sim eu sei, provavelmente será mesmo esse o caso, mas estou na esperança que possa ser outra coisa.

Comment: Tenta realizar os passos recomendados no windows, se não funcionar talvez só entrando em contato com o suporte mesmo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### 1. Ubuntu

Você deve ir como **sudo** até o diretório **/etc/udev/rules.d/** e editar o arquivo **51-android.rules** (se não existir, crie).

Adicione essa linha:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="0bb4", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"
```

Substituindo o `{idVendor}` pelo valor na tabela que ele fornece no site.

Ao final, use: `chmod a+r /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules`, tire e plug o device novamente.

**Além disso, verifique que está rodando tudo com as versões mais novas**.

### 2. Windows*

Se ao instalar o Driver do fabricante e não funcionar, você vai precisar realizar alguns passos.

No gerenciador de dispositivos, procure a seção **Android Phone ou Telefone Android** e expanda.

Clique com botão direito em **Android Composite ADB Interface** e selecione **Update Drivers**.

Selecione **Install from a list or specific location (Instalar de uma lista ou local específico)**

Escolha o Driver do Google (Google USB Driver) que está localizado em **caminho_para_o_sdk\extras\google\usb_driver\** e continue.

<sub>*Alguns desses passos podem ser um pouco diferentes dependendo da versão, qualquer coisa consulte a fonte com instruções específicas para cada versão</sub>

Fonte: [Using Hardware Devices](http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html) e [OEM USB Drivers](http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/oem-usb.html).

Comment: Ainda agora mesmo coloquei o teu primeiro ponto na edição, ainda nem tinha visto a tua resposta, mas a questão é que continua sem funcionar.

Comment: @JorgeB., qual o fabricante do tablet?

Comment: [RFTECH](http://rftech.com.cn) rsrsrs